# SelectMenu keeping selection after message edit

Tags: discord.py

This is using the discord.py 2.0 alpha `SelectMenu`. After editing the original message the selections clears any idea on how to keep the selection after the edit?

I think this is how it should be done but I can't implement that in-code:

- Create a variable that stores `play_status_view()`
- Save the user choice within the object
- Use the new object when editing

```py
class play_status_view(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)


    @discord.ui.select(custom_id="squad_play_status", placeholder="Signup status",
                       min_values=1, max_values=1,
                       options=[discord.SelectOption(label="A"),
                                discord.SelectOption(label="B"),
                                discord.SelectOption(label="C")])
    async def signup_callback(self, select: discord.ui.select, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print(select.values[0])
        

        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=discord.Embed(title='Test'))
        # or 
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=discord.Embed(title='Test'), view=self)
```

Comment: Since this is still in alpha/not publicly available, I doubt you'll find any help here.

Comment: Best to stick to the current release for the time being

Comment: @Dominik it is publicly available on the master branch and the documentation is also available

Comment: @Abdulaziz If you are not on the discord.py server: "*This feature will not be in discord.py until the release of 2.0, which as of now is nowhere near ready. [...]
**Note:** for those intending to install from the master branch to get early access. We urge you to **not** do this. `master` is in a state of flux and as such is not supported by the Helpers or within the help channels. You will be entirely on your own until it releases.*" So I once again doubt you'll find any help here.